# UI Forms events block my other STOCK TICKER API events - how can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, events

I have an API (dll) that collects stock ticks via an event mechanism. Such as below:

```
...
using MT4API;

public partial class Blue : Form
{
...
public Blue()   
        {
...
            string symbol = "GBPUSD";
            MT4DDE dde = new MT4DDE("");
            dde.OnQuote += new System.EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs>(MT_OnQuote);
            dde.Connect();
            dde.Subscribe(symbol);
....
```

The idea is that on each chart tick I get an event. here is the event handler code:

```
    private static void MT_OnQuote(object sender, QuoteEventArgs args)
    {
        GlobalClass.Ask = args.Ask;
        GlobalClass.Bid = args.Bid;
        // I have back ground worker code that updatestables from the global class
    }
```

This all works fine. So long as I do not touch any other buttons on the form UI. As soon as I click a button on the form of the UI... I no longer receive events from my API, the UI application functions normally, but with no data from the API.

Why do events from the UI stop any further events coming from the API event?

Any idea whats going on here? Or suggestions how to design this?

Comment: the background worker code that you took out is likely relevant.

Comment: don't forget to do `Application.DoEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

Does the same problem occur if you comment out your code that updates the tables from the global object? and if you comment out the background worker?

It would be a good idea to distinguish if the event stops being fired just after you press some button on the UI, or if it stops being fired only after some line of code *you* wrote is being executed.

In order to be able to help you, we would need to know how the event on the MT4DDE class is triggered.

If you have the code for this class, posting it would help.

If you don't you may want to use a tool such as Reflector to decompile the assembly into C# and see what the MT4DDE class is doing that might cause it to stop invoking the event.

In addition, if you are doing anything related to background threads, or if you're doing anything unusual with your application's main message loop, it would be a good idea to mention it here.

Comment: The API that I am trying to integrate is located here: http://www.mt4api.net/how-to-use/dde

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use the invoke command, it works, but after a few events it stops...here is the code isolated:

using MT4API;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(double ask, double bid);

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string symbol = "GBPUSD";
        MT4DDE dde = new MT4DDE("");
        dde.OnQuote += new EventHandler<QuoteEventArgs>(MT_OnQuote);
        dde.Connect();
        dde.Subscribe(symbol);

    }

    private void updateTickDisplay(double ask, double bid)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ask.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = bid.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void MT_OnQuote(object sender, QuoteEventArgs args)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new UpdateTextCallback(this.updateTickDisplay),
        new object[] { args.Ask, args.Bid });
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }

}
```

}

The only difference from the real code is that I am using a data grid....as opposed to a text field. But it is clear that the UI blocks somehow the new events. It is strange that I get about 5 to 10 events and then it just stops. Strange. Any ideas on a differnet design?